# Site não puxa as configurações locais de estilo

Tags: php, codeigniter, hospedagem

Utilizo codeigniter na minha aplicação.

No localhost funciona perfeitamente. Utilizo uma pasta *assets* fora da Application, aonde contem todos estes meus arquivos.

o código que eu puxo é este:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css?>" 
   rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

ou

```
 <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/bootstrap.js?>"></script>
```

Quando eu subo na minha hospedagem, as guias funcionam(links e etc) mas os estilos nao vem.. tem algo de errado com meu código?

Comment: Você está fechando a tag do php 2 vezes.

Comment: corrigi as tags do php.. <link href="<?php echo base_url("../assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css"); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> mas ainda nao puxa o assets, estou tentando de todas as formas ! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifique se sua base_url está apontando para o caminho certo quando você subiu a sua hospedagem. No config.php em application/config:

> $config['base_url']   = 'http://www.suahospedagem.com'

Alem disso verifique também o redirecionamento atráves do seu arquivo htaccess